# Ruby String.index("/") return -1

Tags: ruby, string, indexing

I need that the method index return -1 instead of NIL, is there another way? (Ruby programming)

```
index="asddsa".index("/")
if index==nil
    puts -1
else
    puts index
end
```

Comment: How about `'asddsa'.index('/') or -1`?

Answer (score 1):

Just do it yourself:

```
index = "asddsa".index("/") || -1
```

This works because the expression `a = b || c` assigns `b` to `a` if `b` is not `nil`/`false`, and if `b` is `nil`/`false`, it assigns `c` to `a` instead. So in this case, when `String#index` returns `nil`, it assigns `-1` to your `index` variable (and when it returns a number, it just assigns that to `index`).